# Bounded analytic in a region is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function where $G$ is a region in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|\leq|f(\alpha)|$ for some $\alpha\in G$. Then $f$ is a constant function.

Can somebody help how to proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know The Maximum Modulus Theorem?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This is the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

There are a lot of different proofs for this statement, depending on what theorems you have already proved.

You can, for example, deduce it from the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)). I suggest you try proving it for yourself and see where you get. If you get stuck, here's a proof.

> Let us suppose that $f$ is not constant. By the open mapping theorem, $f$ is open. In particular, every neighbourhood of  $a$ is mapped to a set containg a neighbourhood of $f(a)$, which contradicts the maximality of $|f(a)|$.